# ASP.NET Application Development – Tools

Tags: asp.net

We are building an ASP.NET website using C#.NET language and VSTS 2008.

Would you please let me know which are all the third-party tools those can help us in the complete SDLC of this project?

Thank you..

Regards,
Karina.

Comment: what? Can you please rephrase the question

Answer (score 4):

Try Microsoft [Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/dd408382.aspx).  It will handle your source control, work item tracking, bug tracking, reports, and provide you with a Sharepoint project portal.

Answer (score 1):

Phew! There's *lots* that you can use, basically a complete eco-system has been constructed around this.

Much depends on

- the process you'll use to develop the software (waterfall? agile? a mix?)
- where your people are (if you have remote folks, you'll need good collaboration)
- how many you are (small projects won't need quite as much project tracking software)
- the kind of project you're on (a large complex site might need a comprehensive database management system, a small one can just use free tools)
- what metrics you need to report
- how experienced your developers are
- the kind of graphic design expertise you have and need
- your budget!

And that's just off the top of my head.

More specifically, here's some third-party tools I've used successfully that I'd not consider starting a project of any size without:

- A source code repository: [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) is a good one, TFS is expensive but does the job
- A continuous integration server: I prefer [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org), others like [CruiseControl.NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET)
- A refactoring tool for software developers ([Refactor](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Refactoring/)!, [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/))
- A virtual machine system for hosting test systems on a server (I use VMWare)

For larger teams where you're using Agile methodologies and need to report progress, consider Scrumworks.

Putting it another way, I'd suggest that you budget at least $500 per developer for tools, add-ons and geegaws beyond Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

At home I use:

tortoises - Source Control - http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/
ankhsvn - VS Integration - http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/
CruiseControl.Net - Continuous Integration - http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET
Screwturn wiki - wiki for knowledge sharing - http://www.screwturn.eu/

At work I use TFS.